# How to return values from an angular-modal-service modal

Tags: angularjs

### Angular.js modal and controller scope issue

My current Angular 1.x application work as follows - I have tempplate, let's call it 'view' which calls a function on ng-click, the button example:

```
<div ng-controller="viewController as listing">
     <button ng-click="listing.openModal()" ng-disabled="listing.isButtonDisabled">
</div>
```

```js
$scope.isButtonDisabled = false;
$scope.openModal = ModalService();
```

The controller for the view uses a factory which opens the modal, I use a factory since severalcontrollers use the same modal functionality. As can be seen from above I do not disable the button initisally.

The modal pops open and it has it's own controller that is concerned with the input received from the user in the modal. When the input has been processed, if successful I want to disable the button on the original view which opens the modal.

The problem as i see it is that I am out of scope in my new controller - if I do this:

```
$scope.isButtonDisabled = true;
```

It will apply to the scope of the modal, not the original view which calls for the modal to open?

**UPDATE**

I am using this angular modal service:

[Angular Modal Service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service)

I created this Plunker to demonstrate my code:

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i7XuHw4iqBqugaXmHpd3?p=preview)

Comment: You need to be able to return a value from your service which means it needs to return a promise that you can then resolve. If you use the [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) library it has a `$uibModal` directive that handles all this for you.

Comment: Returning values from a modal depend on the particular modal library that the app uses. The `$uibModal` service does it differently than the `$mdDialog` service. It is hard to help you with your `ModalService` without seeing its code or documentation.

Comment: Keep in mind that modal dialogs can double error rates, increase time to task completion, and are near-universally despised by users. Alternate means of notification are often available and should be utilized wherever possible and appropriate. See - [What research is there suggesting modal dialogs are disruptive?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-research-is-there-suggesting-modal-dialogs-are-disruptive)

Comment: @georgeawg Please see my updated question with a link to my Plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DOCs:

> Calling `showModal` returns a promise which is resolved when the modal DOM element is created and the controller for it is created. The promise returns a `modal` object which contains the element created, the controller, the scope and two promises: `close` and `closed`. Both are resolved to the result of the modal `close` function, but `close` is resolved as soon as the modal `close` function is called, while `closed` is only resolved once the modal has finished animating and has been completely removed from the DOM.
>
> — [GitHub: angular-modal-service README - Usage](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service#usage)

The service should return the promise:

```
app.service('FooBar', function FooBar(ModalService) {

    this.openModal = function(template, controller) {
        
        // Note: in order to fire the modal pop-up the id of the script tag 
        //of the modal should match the first param of ng-click on the button
        // eg. <script type="text/ng-template" id="messageSeller">
        // should match: ng-click="openModal('messageSeller',
        //                         'messagesAddController')"

        //IMPORTANT return promise
        ̶M̶o̶d̶a̶l̶S̶e̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶.̶s̶h̶o̶w̶M̶o̶d̶a̶l̶(̶{̶
        return ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: template, // <- ensure the value of template
                                   // matches the id of one of the modal divs     
            controller: controller,
            inputs: {}
        })
    };
})
```

Use the returned promise in the controller:

```
app.controller('Controller', function(FooBar) {

    var listing = this;
    listing.isButtonDisabled = false;
    
    listing.openModal = function(template, controller){
        FooBar(template, controller)
          .then(function(model) {
            return modal.close;
        }).then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
            listing.isButtonDisabled = true;
        }).catch(function(reason) {
            console.log("Modal error:", reason);
        });                
    }
});
```

Disable the button when the modal successfully returns a value.

Comment: Does this look better: https://plnkr.co/edit/iDUyezgFjwI93lxOmijK?p=preview